# Hide res folder in apk reverse engineering

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, android-proguard

I want to restrict my app from reverse engineering.

Using progaurd hides only source code

But not res folder: drawable folder, layout folder, color, strings all are visible

When i am trying to check from online tools like apk editor
i can see my res folder

Please help me how to hide res folder

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to protect drawable resource in Android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4952630/how-to-protect-drawable-resource-in-android-application) . It's a duplicate question and you'll find in the link provided a lot of details about this. It can be achieved, but there are some downsides for it and is not 100% secure. In the end however, it's best to let them as they are.

Comment: any way we can hide res folder

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can hide the res folder in final apk. Even if you manage to do it by some encryption, it will be highly discourage since it will have severe performance impact.

`res` folder shouldn't have any sensitive data which needs such protection. If your intention is to have some sensitive data, then put it in `assets` folder and use tools like `dexguard` to encrypt it.